# How to read file line by line in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

In Java 8 I see new method is added called lines() in Files class which can be used to read a file line by line in Java. Does it work for huge files? I mean can we load first 1000 lines then second set of 1000 lines. I have huge file with 1GB, Will it work?

Could someone share code snippet how to use it?

Comment: Why don't you try for yourself? And yes, it will work.

Comment: What did you try? As the documentation suggest, that the reading is lazily, this means file size should matter little (except if you are then storing each line, of course).

Comment: It works with the java 8 stream api. So it will also work for huge files

Comment: Every solution works with huge files, as long as you have sufficient memory and patience. You have to be more specific regarding your constraints and the actual operation you want to perform. As you can find out yourself by reading the documentation, the method itself is designed to work by not reading everything into memory at the same time, in principle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it work for huge files? [...] I have huge file with 1GB, Will it
>   work?

As far as I can see it should work well for big files as well (but I haven't tried):

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)){
    lines.filter(...).map(...)....foreach(...);
}
```

> I mean can we load first 1000 lines then second set of 1000 lines.

How many lines are read at one time is implementation specific to Files.lines (which probably uses a BufferedReader, but I might be wrong).

Comment: You need use a try-with-resources block because the stream is not automatically closed.

Answer (score 0):

From the API (embolden by me)

> Read all lines from a file as a Stream. Unlike readAllLines, this method does not read all lines into a List, but instead **populates lazily as the stream is consumed.**

This very strongly suggests that you can use this on any arbitrarily sized file, assuming your code doesn't hold all of the content in memory.